# Why two forms for annotating style of text?

Tags: fonts, formatting, fontsize

When I want text to be large I say:

```
{\Large lorem}
```

When I want text to be bold I say:

```
\textbf{lorem}
```

Why the inconsistency? What's the implementation detail or philosophy behind these two different forms?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're missing the fact that there's also

```
{\bfseries lorem}
```

Font-switching/formatting commands come in two varieties: A command that takes an argument and applies its formatting only to that argument (`\textbf{lorem}`), and a switch that will apply until counteracted by another switch or the end of the group the switch was enabled within (`{\bfseries lorem}`). Note that the "argument form" is meant for short text fragments, as it doesn't allow a paragraph end within its argument.

One can imagine font size commands like `\textlarge` which would act like `\textbf`. IMO, the reason that the former commands don't exist is that (contrary to formatting commands) there's no practical need to switch to another font size for short text fragments. Non-standard font sizes are rather used, e.g., for footnotes and perhaps quotes, and the font size switch is part of the respective command/environment definition.

Comment: That's a good way to look at it. Using the terminology of CSS, large is a property for blocks, while bold is an inline property. Thanks.

Comment: another reason for not having `\textlarge{hello}` is that `{\large hello}` is almost always wrong. Size change commands should always include the blank line or `\par` at end of paragraph as the lines are given a baselineskip based on the settings at the _end_ of the paragraph.