# Why are text format commands used inside braces?

Tags: formatting, fontsize, braces, syntax

Most commands in Latex are written with the arguments inside braces following the command: `\command{arguments}`. But text formatting options, like `\em`, or `\scriptsize` are usually written *inside* the braces, like `{\em some italicised text}`. Why is this? What makes these commands different? I'm particularly asking because it seems to make standardisation - of which LaTeX really appears badly in need - more difficult.

Comment: Commands such as `\em` and `\scriptsize` have no argument; they function as ‘switches’. The surrounding braces form a group so that changes are only local.

Comment: A recent question [How to write math symbols](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63735/how-to-write-maths-symbols) contains relevant information and pointers about this

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57062/why-two-forms-for-annotating-style-of-text

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There *is* a standard. It's a matter of opinion whether it's sensible or not, but it's been there since the release of LaTeX2e.

1. Font aspect changing commands have two forms: *action* and *declaration*
2. The same holds for abstract instruction such as "emphasize"
3. Size changing commands have only the declarative form.

Let me review the three points.

### Font aspect changing commands

The declarative form for changing the font's aspect is formed from a prefix denoting briefly the purpose and by a suffix denoting the attribute that's changed:

```
\sffamily
\itshape
\bfseries
```

The "action form" is a command that takes an argument; all kernel defined commands of this type have a prefix `text` and a suffix corresponding to the similar declaration:

```
\textsf{words}
\textit{words}
\textbf{words}
```

The fundamental difference is that a declaration's scope is up to the end of the group in which it's issued (or a countermanding declaration).

Two important commands are `\textnormal` (action) and `\normalfont` (declaration) that instruct LaTeX to use the font which was current at document start.

### Abstract instruction

By "abstract instruction" I mean `\emph` and `\em`, which *usually* act by italicizing, but one should not rely on this, as the effect can be redefined by the document class.

The form `\emph` is the action: `\emph{words}`, while `\em` is a declaration. The latter can be useful in defining environments.

### Size changing commands

The size changing commands have only the declarative form, as very rarely one needs to set a couple of words in a smaller or larger size. Examples

```
\footnotesize
\small
\normalsize
\large
```

Their scope ends with the group where they have been issued (usually an environment). If a paragraph must be typeset in a different size it's important to remember marking explicitly the end with `\par` or a blank line. Commonly it's the environment where they are issued that takes care of it.

Answer (score 24):

As @egreg has explained, partly it is the way it is because that's just how it is (and was in latex2.09 and plain tex).

Apart from just being a syntax choice, there are also efficiency considerations. As a switch you can go `\large` at the beginning of a document and the whole document goes large (it is an *assignment* as if the syntax were

```
\setlength\currentsize{1in}
```

On the other hand if the syntax were `\large{.....}` then *the whole document* would have to be parsed as an *argument* this would have implications on TeX's memory requirements (and would probably not have been possible for that reason alone in the early days) as well as meaning that `\verb` and other catcode changing features could not be used in the scope of such a command.

If you do not like the assignment/switch model and prefer to use a different syntax then LaTeX does offer an alternative that looks more "LaTeX-like" and does not have the problems with parsing massive macro arguments:

```
\begin{large}
....
\end{large}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a great addendum to egreg's answer. If I could accept both, I would.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the very good answers already given: The action form (e.g. `\emph{...}`) may do more than the declarative form (`{\em ...}`). In the case of `\emph` it's automatic italic correction, for example.

Comment: Well, `\def\em{\it\aftergroup\/} {\em Testing} 1,2,3\par {\it Testing\/} 1,2,3\par {\it Testing} 1,2,3 \bye` at least does the same thing.