# Use of large font extends for remainder of LaTeX document, Error?

Tags: fontsize

I am using the `\large` font command in a document and it seems that the large font extends beyond my intended text to the end of the document.  Example of code:

```
...
<previous text>
\newpage
\large{Examples of Continuous Symmetry}
<more text>
...
```

Now, from the point of `\large{xxx}` to the end of the document, all text is in the large font.  I have tried various things to find the problem including removing the `\newpage` or even deleting and rewriting the \large command statement.

I use the `\large` command at earlier positions in the paper but it works as expected which is the only portion in large font is that contained in braces `{}`.

Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug.  I downloaded latest Mac version of TeX software just yesterday.  I use TeXShop as the editor environment.

Note: please excuse my choice of tags as I am unsure of the correct tag to use.

Comment: `\large` has no argument, it is a switch. Use `{\large Text \par}`

Comment: the syntax is `{\large xxxxx <blank line>]` not `\large{xxx}`

Comment: Note you should almost never have a font change command in a document, if that is a section heading it should be `\section*{Examples of Continuous Symmetry}`

Comment: maybe even better duplicate: [Why are text format commands used inside braces?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64480/579)

Comment: Thanks very much for the answers and new information.  As far as using a \section and other things, I would if this document were worthy of doing things neatly but it is merely my own personal notes: no chapters, not really any sections, just text mixed with equations here and there.

Comment: So, I was wondering why things seemed to work with my previous invocations of \large{some text} and I noticed in looking back (something I missed before) that this \large command was nested in a \textbf{...} command and I presume that the \textbf closed the extent of \large.

Comment: @K7PEH the personal notes argument doesn't really apply as (as you see) it's harder and takes more markup, and produces a poorer result, to use low level font and size commands than it is to use the structured markup for sections.