# Why do \large and \textbf require different usage of braces?

Tags: formatting, fontsize, braces, parameters

`\large` and other font size commands need to be placed inside a group:

```
In this text {\large some part} is large.
```

[image: screenshot]

Whereas `\textbf` and other styling commands receive a parameter:

```
In this text \textbf{some part} is bold.
```

[image: screenshot]

Why the difference?

Comment: `\large` is a switch, whereas `\textbf{...}` is a command with an argument. The corresponding switch is `\bfseries`. Actually  `\textbf{...}` is the same as `{\bfseries ...}`

Comment: Related, although the present question is phrased more clearly: [Braces inside or outside?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/367882/579)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\textbf{stuff}` (roughly) does `{\bfseries stuff}`, which is the counterpart for `\large` you are looking for. `\textbf` is defined in terms of `\bfseries` with:

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textbf}{\bfseries}
```

You can do the same to create a `\textlarge`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textlarge}{\large}
\begin{document}
In this text \textlarge{some part} is large.
\end{document}
```